# How to create in draft-js a new EditorState from a SelectionState

Tags: reactjs, copy-paste, draftjs

In a draft js editor, I would like to allow the user to select part of text in the editor and then click a button, which should grab the selected part and transform it into an EditorState (which I can persist as raw). But I cannot figure out how to get from the SelectionState, that I get from editorState.getSelection() to a new EditorState.
What I have so far is:

````
export const getSelectedText = (editorState: EditorState): string => {
  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection()
  const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent()
  return getTextSelection(currentContent, selectionState, '\n')
}

const getTextSelection = (
  contentState: ContentState,
  selection: Draft.SelectionState,
  blockDelimiter: string
) => {
  const myBlockDelimiter = blockDelimiter || '\n'
  const startKey = selection.getStartKey()
  const endKey = selection.getEndKey()
  const blocks = contentState.getBlockMap()
  let lastWasEnd = false
  const selectedBlock = blocks
    .skipUntil((block) => {
      return block?.getKey() === startKey
    })
    .takeUntil((block) => {
      const result = lastWasEnd

      if (block?.getKey() === endKey) {
        lastWasEnd = true
      }

      return result
    })

  return selectedBlock
    .map((block) => {
      const key = block?.getKey() || ''
      const text = block?.getText() || ''
      const start = key === startKey ? selection.getStartOffset() : 0
      const end = key === endKey ? selection.getEndOffset() : text.length
      return text.slice(start, end)
    })
    .join(myBlockDelimiter)
}```
which gives me the pure text, but loses all the formatting.
````

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out myself. At least in principle. Here some code:

````
  const selectionState = editorState.getSelection()
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
  const entityMap = contentState.getEntityMap()
  const startKey = selectionState.getStartKey()
  const endKey = selectionState.getEndKey()
  const blocks = contentState.getBlockMap()
  let lastWasEnd = false
  const selectedBlocks = blocks
    .skipUntil((block) => {
      return block?.getKey() === startKey
    })
    .takeUntil((block) => {
      const result = lastWasEnd
      if (block?.getKey() === endKey) {
        lastWasEnd = true
      }

      return result
    })
  const blockArray: Array<ContentBlock> = []
  selectedBlocks.forEach((bloke) => {
    if (bloke) {
      blockArray.push(bloke)
    }
  })
  const newContentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
    blockArray,
    entityMap
  )
  return EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState)
}```
the major obstacle for me here was the conversion of the selectedBlocks, which are of type  Immutable.Iterable<string, Draft.ContentBlock> into an Array of type ContentBlock, which is done by the forEach block.
What this part of code is not doing, is to take care of truncating the text, it the selection cuts within a block.
````

Answer (score 0):

I think your `block` variable has some formatting there and you are not returning the formatting when you used the map function.

````
    .map((block) => {
      const key = block?.getKey() || ''
      const text = block?.getText() || ''
      const start = key === startKey ? selection.getStartOffset() : 0
      const end = key === endKey ? selection.getEndOffset() : text.length
      return { ...block, text.slice(start, end)}
    })
    .join(myBlockDelimiter)```
Just a helpful idea to keep the props and change only what you want to change using spread operators. it may not work perfectly as we do not know what you state variables looks like atm.
````

Comment: yes, I know, sorry, I maybe should not have posted this piece. It just returns the text. But my problem is: how can I create from a selection a new EditorState which contains just the selection, including formats?